# How to condense multiple update statement - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update statement for 10 columns which is replacing values in each of the column with a where condition to that specific column.

Here's the code:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = REPLACE(Col1, '#DIV/0', NULL)
WHERE Col1 = '#DIV/0';


UPDATE Table1
SET Col2 = REPLACE(Col2, '#DIV/0', NULL)
WHERE Col2 = '#DIV/0';


UPDATE Table1
SET Col3 = REPLACE(Col3, '#DIV/0', NULL)
WHERE Col3 = '#DIV/0';
```

Like this I have it for 10 columns, it does the work but it doesn't look clear or professional.

I wanted to condense this code and make it look like a professional code.

Any suggestions is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this technique.  You would over-complicate the problem to try to combine these into one statement.

Comment: Ohhh.... So it's better I leave it as it is?

Comment: I would say yes, but I like Peter B's improvement

Comment: Couldn't add code in a comment, so added my 2¢ as separate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you leave it as it is, with one change because statements such as `REPLACE(Col1, '#DIV/0', NULL)` do not make sense: calling REPLACE in sql server where any parameter is NULL always produces NULL, regardless if the text is found or not.

So best is this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Col1 = NULL WHERE Col1 = '#DIV/0';
UPDATE Table1 SET Col2 = NULL WHERE Col2 = '#DIV/0';
UPDATE Table1 SET Col3 = NULL WHERE Col3 = '#DIV/0';
```

Comment: This is even more shorter, Thanks :) +1

Comment: This answer is more clean and shorter. @jarlh - No offence pls.

Comment: @UnknownUser, no problem. Highly data dependent which solution which is best. (How many percent of the rows/columns need to be updated. Indexes etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Use `case` expressions keep the old value if it's not equal to `'#DIV/0'`, the default `else null` will replace the `'#DIV/0'` values with NULL.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET
Col1 = case when Col1 <> '#DIV/0' then Col1 end,
Col2 = case when Col2 <> '#DIV/0' then Col2 end,
...
```

Note that all rows will be updated, i.e. one huge transaction. If that's a problem, either go back to your original solution with several updates, or add this at the end:

```
where '#DIV/0' in (Col1, Col2, ...)
```

If this is a good or bad idea depends on the data, how many percent of the rows/columns need to be updated. Indexes etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess this does help me. Thanks again. +1. couldn't accept the answer still coz of the timer.

Comment: It will work, however if you have 5 billion rows and just a few that actually need changing, this will still update all 5 billion of them.

Comment: @PeterB, that's why I pointed out the huge transaction, and later added some additional text. Better now, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its T-SQL, why not just use NULLIF function

```
DECLARE ValToNull AS VARCHAR(10) = '#DIV/0'

UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = NULLIF(Col1, ValToNull),
Col2 = NULLIF(Col2, ValToNull),
Col3 = NULLIF(Col3, ValToNull)
```